# Insert XAML into WPF custom control in the editor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a XAML main window that contains a header, a central area and a footer (in a grid). The central area contains a ContentControl which is set throw a binding (using MVVMLight). The header/footer is always the same so no problems there.

The part that goes into the `ContentControl` is always quite similar, they are WPF usercontrols and have a left part that contains info and a right part with at least an OK and BACK button.

These are viewmodels and their views:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock Text="this changes and contains other controls too" />            
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <!-- more buttons and statuses-->
        <Button Content="Back" Margin="5" Height="30" />
        <Button Content="Ok" Margin="5" Height="30" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Is there a way i could create a base class/custom control for those views?** So that I could write something like this in my xaml:

```
<basewindow>
    <leftpart>
        custom XAML for this view
    </leftpart>
    <rightpart>
        custom XAML for this view
    </rightpart>
</basewindow>
```

**I could then remove duplicate code that is now in each of those views to the base class while still keeping the ability to write my xaml in the editor. Or is this not feasible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify are you trying to inherit the visual element that exist in XAML, like you can do in WinForms?  If so you cannot do this in WPF.  There is no Visual inheritence in WPF.

Now if you aren't trying to inherit visual element it is easy.  First create your UserControlBase class and add you event handler.  Keep in mind this base class can not have any XAML associated with it.  Code only

```
public class MyUserControlBase : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControlBase()
    {

    }

    protected virtual void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Now create another UserControl that does have a xaml counter part.  Now you will need to change the root elemtn in the XAML to your base class like this:

```
<local:MyUserControlBase x:Class="WpfApplication7.MyUserControl"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7">

<Grid>
   <Button Click="Button_Click">My Button</Button>
</Grid>
</local:MyUserControlBase>
```

And don't forget the code behind:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : MyUserControlBase
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Notice the button in the derived user control is calling the Button_Click event handler we defined in the base class.  That is all you need to do.